# Have I implemented a pure virtual function wrong?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, virtual

**EDIT:**

> I have no updated the question, whilst doing so I realized the scope of the question has completely changed, so I apologize for this. I am dealing with Threads so that static function has to be there. I have tried to abstract the Threading stuff out of the question as much as possible.

I am getting a `pure virtual function call` error, so I thought maybe I have the implementation wrong. Here is what I have:

```
class Base
{
    protected:
        virtual int f(void) = 0;
        static void baseFunction(void* param);
};

static void Base::baseFunction (void* param)
{
    Base *parent = (Base*) parameter;

    int i = parent->f();
}

class Derived : public Base
{
    private:
        int _memeber;
        int f(void);
};

int Derived::f(void)
{
    _member = 0;

    cout << "Derived _memeber is: " << _member << endl;

    return 0;
}

void main ()
{
    Derived d;

    d.baseFunction(d);
}
```

I need the function `Derived::f(void)` to have access to the `Derived` class members.

Comment: Is this the actual code? There is no semi-colon to after definition of either class.

Comment: Also, the definition should say `int Derived::f(void)`. But when are you getting the error? Is it a compiler or a runtime error? Are you sure you're calling the `Derived` one?

Comment: The code, as-is (modulo the remark by hmjd), is good. There should be another problem somewhere.

Comment: And `Derived::f(void)` must return an `int`.

Comment: And Derived::foo(void) needs a return type, and you don't need/want the 'void' in 'foo(void)'.

Comment: And I'm not sure I like the `protected` in the Base, as the one in Derived is `public`.

Comment: Where are you using the `Derived` object? Are you passing it by value to a function expecting a `Base`? If so it will be sliced and the virtual function won't exist at runtime.

Comment: Can you post a compilable example, along with details of the compiler?

Comment: The definition looks fine. How are you calling the virtual function?

Comment: @PeterWood: It couldn't be slicing - the pure virtual function prevents instantiation of the base class.

Comment: I appologise to all, with my latest edit I realize the whole question scope has changed. I believe its a polymorphic problem. I am dealing with threads so static function has to be static. I tried to abstract the problem as much as possible.

Comment: Once I fix the syntax errors in your code, I see no such error: http://ideone.com/bjWSr. Could you post code that (a) compiles, and (b) demonstrates the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition looks fine, but I will hazard a guess that you're calling the virtual function from the constructor or destructor of `Base`. In that case, virtual dispatch is done as if the dynamic type were `Base`, not `Derived`, and if the function is pure virtual then you get undefined behaviour.

UPDATE: You also say "I am dealing with threads". In that case, it's possible that a data race could cause one thread to call the function while another is still constructing the object - again, giving undefined behaviour. You need to make sure all data accesses are correctly synchronised.

Comment: +1: VC10 detectes this and reports as "unresolved", VC9 throwed "pure virtual function call" error

Comment: Interesting, I removed the parameters from the constructor of the Derived class and I no longer get any issues as soon as I add them back I get an issue. So doing this : `Derived d;` works, but doing this: `Derived d = Derived(param)` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, just missing semicolons after the class declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Add return type to the Derived method. Also add semicolons after class definitions

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return type for f and ; after class definitions

Change your code to

```
class Base
{
    protected:
        virtual int f(void) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        int f(void);
};

int Derived::f(void)
{
    // do something here
}
```

Further, post runnable code if possible. Iow add

```
int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.f();
}
```

to your code sample

Answer (score 0):

Make all your functions in your two classes public. And why are you declaring int i? it's not used at all.

Answer (score -2):

you need to declare

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    protected:
        virtual int f(void);
}
```

I suppose your pure virtual function call comes from Base class using f in another of it's methods.

Comment: Or calling `f` from the base class constructor.

Comment: No, declaring the method `virtual` in the base class makes it virtual in all derived classes. You don't need to specify `virtual` in children.